# getting forbidden 403 error while logging into a website Python

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I am trying to login into a website (using python requests) by passing user name and password in get.
But getting 403 forbidden error. I am able to login into the website through browser using the same credentials.

I have tried using different headers but nothing seems to be working.

I have tried all commented headers. also the proxy. This is basically a VB code we need t convert in python. In VB they have used proxy hence tried using proxy.

I need to login into the website and download a file abc.csv

code:

```
# Import library
import requests
# Define url, username, and password
url = 'https://example.com'
#r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
#s = requests.Session()
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
#headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic" , "Pragma" : "no-cache","If-Modified-Since": "Thu, 01 Jun 1970 00:00:00 GMT",'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
#headers={'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Thu, 23 Sep 2021 12:44:25 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
proxies= {"https":"http://10.10.10.10:8080"}
r=requests.get(url,proxies=proxies),headers=headers)
requests.post(url, data={"username":"user","password":"pwd"})
#s.get(url)

# send a HTTP request to the server and save
# the HTTP response in a response object called r
with open("abc.csv",'wb') as f:

# Saving received content as a png file in
# binary format

# write the contents of the response (r.content)
# to a new file in binary mode.
r.write(r.content)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hey, credentials aren't sent by data, but tru auth. Check https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/ fr more informations.

Comment: The HTTP 403 is an HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill it. I think to solve this you need some sort of a key.

Comment: @Leemosh tried passing through auth, still getting 403.

Comment: Nowadays using requests in anything then getting simple ressources like you could with curl is pretty much assured to fail. There is a lot to handle: hidden fields, cookies, etc.

I recommend taking a more modern approch with ie. Playwright https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python. There are other alternatives (Puppeteer, Selenium, ...) Playwright being the most recent and easy to use.